# How to refresh a bindingsource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is really driving me nuts, I have a datagridview  bound to a bindingsource, on the click of a button I add new objects to my database using my datacontext, how can I make the binding source to show the new objects in my datagrid? I already tried setting the datasource of the binding source again but it wont work, eventhough the new datasource does return the new objects in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways, either you have to bind the datasource again or you should implement the inotifypropertychanged interface

Answer (score 1):

> I already tried setting the datasource of the binding source again but it wont work

Set it to null, *then* set it to the actual data source again. It should do the trick...