# update list which is from bindingsource

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have got a datagridview which is databind to a bindingsource, that bindingsource is a list....what i did was to update the value at the datagridview but the list did not get updated.

```
 private void BindDataSourceToGridview()
 {
 BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
 bindingSource.DataSource = objectList;
 datagridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = false
 datagridview1.DataSource = bindingSource;

 reCalculateIndex(datagridView1);

 datagridview1.EndEdit();
 datagridview1.Refresh();
 }

 private void reCalculateIndex(Datagridview datagridView)
 {
 int index = 1;
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridView.rows)
 {
 row.Cells[0].Value = index;
 index++;
 }
 }
```

how can i refresh the list after doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check this: [How to refresh a bindingsource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348593/how-to-refresh-a-bindingsource)

It suggests to try to set the DataSource to null and then reset to the objectList value. As an alternative you can implement the inotifypropertychanged interface

Comment: my case is alittle bit different, ive got the gridview displayed nicely but the underlying objectList which is the datasource did not get updated when i tried to use it somewhere else